# Classical decision theory as a particular case of the Bayesian approach?

Tags: probability, statistics

In the Bayesian approach to decision theory, in the case of a simple hypothesis where the choice has to be made between the hypothesis $H_0$ and $H_1$, one is lead to compute the posterior probabilities $P(H_0|x)$ and $P(H_1|x)$, where $x$ is the observed data. One has the Bayes relation:

$\frac{P(H_1|x)}{P(H_0|x)}=\frac{L(x|H_1)}{L(x|H_0)}\frac{P(H_1)}{P(H_0)}$

where the prior probabilitis and the likelyhoods appear.

**Question:**  We can consider the following simple decision rule (without introducing loss functions as it is often made): choose $H_1$ if the probability $\frac{P(H_1|x)}{P(H_0|x)}>\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is a parameter to be chosen. Otherwise choose $H_0$.  Told another way the rejection region is of the form $C=\{x| \frac{L(x|H_1)}{L(x|H_0)} > \alpha'\}$. Where $\alpha'=\alpha\frac{P(H_0)}{P(H_1)}$. This is exactly a rejection region of the form derived in classical decision making by the Neyman-Pearson lemma. Can we say therefore that classical decision making is just a particular form of the Bayesian approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

First, Neyman–Pearson hypothesis testing is not the same as Fisher hypothesis testing, and so when you say "classical decision making", you need to decide which one you think is *classical*.

Second, the implicit Bayesian value for $\alpha$ in a likelihood ratio test depends on the prior distribution and the loss function, while the Neyman–Pearson hypothesis test bases it on significance level (the probability of a Type I error if the null hypothesis is true).

Third, it gets more complicated when testing a composite alternative hypothesis.

You can read more for example at http://www.mathstat.ualberta.ca/~wiens/stat665/TAS%20-%20testing.pdf

If you want to explore the issue yourself, try this simple example and consider tossing a coin $200$ times and getting $115$ heads, with the hypotheses:

- $H_0$: the coin is fair with the probability of heads $p=\frac12$
- $H_1$: the coin is unfair with the probability of heads $p \not =\frac12$

Try testing the hypotheses with

1. a Fisher test: is the probability of observing $115$ out of $200$ heads or a more extreme result more or less than $5\%$?
2. a Neyman–Pearson test: is the likelihood ratio for $\frac{\mathbb{P}\left(115\text{ heads }\mid p=\frac{115}{200}\right)}{\mathbb{P}\left(115\text{ heads }\mid p=\frac{1}{2}\right)}$ high enough to reject $H_0$?
3. a Bayesian test, supposing that *a priori* $H_0$ and $H_1$ are equally likely, that the loss for making a wrong decision is $1$ either way, and that under $H_1$ the prior distribution for $p$ is uniform on $[0,1]$

Then try to distort the Bayesian test so that it in some sense matches the Neyman–Pearson test.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am going definetely to read that pdf which deals exactly with my doubt! I was anyway comparing to Neyman-Pearson as I wrote: my book does not refer to Fisher for the moment.    For your second point, is it so important that $\alpha$ depends on the prior? What I was observing in my question is that there is a clear mapping between the two decision strategies (and I showed a mapping between the parameters) and in this sense they were equivalent to me... what is the error in this way of thinking?

Comment: @Thomas: I think my point (as illustrated in my example and the example in the link) is that even in fairly simple cases it can be difficult to translate a Neyman–Pearson likelihood ratio test into something intuitively meaningful. While it has the merit of using the likelihood principle, it only really works for two simple hypotheses and even then confuses whether it is following the Fisher approach (rejecting or not rejecting the null hypothesis, treating Type I and II errors separately) and the Bayesian position (taking a decision between two alternatives with errors being comparable)

Comment: Just to be sure I understood your last sentence.... Do you want to say: 1) Neyman-Pearson is not equal to the Fisher approach because if treats Type I and type II errors differently, whereas the Fisher approach does not even consider them; 2) Neyman-Pearson is not equal to the Bayesian approach because type I and type II errors are not weighted by the procedure;

Comment: (reading literature I read about an other type of approach, called "Null hypothesis significance testing", which should be a controversial hybrid of Fisher and Neyman Pearson. Do you have also any reference on that?)

Comment: I put my last comment into a separate question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1877966/difference-between-nhst-and-fisher-approach , since here is maybe off-topic and not related to the original one