# Difference between NHST and Fisher approach to decision theory

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

Is there a difference between the NHST (null hypothesis statistical test) and the Fisher approach to decision theory? I could not find any difference, since it seems to me that they both ignore the alternative hypothesis (which is not ignored for example by the Neyman-Pearson and Bayes approach). But maybe I have problems in finding in the literature a clear description of NHST.

Answer (score 1):

Fisher focused mainly on looking at the probability of outcomes computed
under the assumption that the null hypothesis is true. Consider his
famous example of a lady tasting tea. She claims tea tastes better if
the milk is put into the cup before the tea is poured, than if milk is
added after the tea is poured. To test whether she can really tell
the difference, she is confronted with eight cups randomly arranged on
a tray---four prepared each way. (She is told to pick the four cups
that taste best.) Fisher would conclude she can indeed tell the difference if she
picks the four milk-first cups, because there is only one chance in ${8 \choose 4} = 70$ of this outcome under the null hypothesis that she cannot distinguish
orders of pouring. Fisher developed many kinds of hypothesis tests along
these lines, including what we call ANOVA (analysis of variance).

A few years later Neyman and Pearson formulated the framework of acceptance
and rejection regions, type I and type II error probabilities, and power.
Fisher strongly resisted this framework and apparently especially the idea
of power. For the tea-tasting experiment, Neyman & Pearson might have wanted to know the chances that the lady could 'pass' Fisher's test if she had some
moderate, but not perfect, ability to distinguish order of pouring. (For example, 
maybe she can do it for only 80% of the cups she tastes.)

Apparently, it is possible for bright people to read the writings of Fisher
on the one hand and Neyman & Pearson on the other hand, and come to remarkably
different conclusions about what each is saying and the distinction between
their philosophies of hypothesis testing. I have tried to stick to what
I view as the clearest and simplest descriptions of the differences. Even so, *I will
not be surprised if there are lots of Comments trying to 'reinterpret', 'clarify', or 'correct' what I have said.* (Perhaps some from people who
have never read a word of the writings of Fisher or of Neyman & Pearson.)

What is totally obvious is that there was a long and bitter battle
of Fisher vs. Neyman & Pearson over fundamental ideas of hypothesis testing.
Fortunately, most texts attempt to explain the formulation and testing of
hypotheses is a way that makes sense to students without feeling the need
to go into past controversies.

*Note (probably unrelated to your specific question)*: There is also a Bayesian approach to hypothesis testing. It is somewhat
controversial but not in a way directly related to the Fisher vs Neyman-Pearson
debate. Very roughly, a Bayesian might require a higher level of proof
if the lady claims she can tell the difference in order of pouring by
closing her eyes and (without smelling or tasting) sensing 'vibrations in the cup's aura' that she claims differ by order of pouring. And a lower level of proof if she only
claims that Darjeeling and Earl Grey teas differ noticeably in taste. Bayesians start out with a 'prior probability' that the lady has the ability she claims,
and put that together with the observational data to get a 'posterior probability', which they use to make an inference.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! but I still do not understand which is the difference between NHST and Fisher method. I was reading this text https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1603/1603.07408.pdf which site NHST as a fouth way, in addition to Fisher, Neyman-Pearson and Bayes. Do you know what the method in the title of the article is referring to?

Comment: I know citing external pdf's is bad practice, but forgive me ones :)

Comment: I have scanned the article. I consider myself to be a inquisitive type guy, but nothing I saw during the scan made me want to go deeper. Happily, 'NHST' is not a common acronym. If you are a New Zealand academic, then maybe there are points of view here that you should understand because you may have to deal with them. If you are a student fairly new to hypothesis testing, I offer the opinion that there are better ways than fussing over this article to make sense of the topic. If you are somewhere in between and have the time to spare, you have a right to make your own choices how to spend it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your opinion. I am somewhat in between but in any case a beginner of the subject. I will follow your advice and not try to insist on this NHST if you say it's not standard stuff...

Comment: I'm saying that I have never seen the acronym _NHST_ before. I would have to read carefully to see what nuances of the discussion differ from what many texts regard as a "standard" presentation. It is clear that what I would regard as fine-grained distinctions in philosophy and presentation are discussed.